# Crop text if longer than Cell Width in fPDF?

Tags: php, fpdf

I have a cell in fPDF which is 50mm wide which is populated from a field in a database. Is there a way I can crop the text so that it doesn't go beyond 50mm if the field contains a lot of text?

Alternatively is there a way in PHP to crop a string based on it's mm length when printed at a specific font size?

Answer (score 0):

A Cell of size 100mm can contains approx 75 character of font size 8. So Try to get your adject text length by manually with above hint.

But What I suggest better use `MultiCell()` for dynamic text size.